# How to solve the problem that the image is not visible when uploading an image inside React-Quill?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-quill

I'm working on a simple bulletin board with React-Quill. I'm implementing to communicate and save the content value to the server, but when uploading an image, there is an error that the image is not displayed in the content, so I can't solve it.

How can I solve this?

```
function Post() {

  const   QuillRef = useRef<ReactQuill>()
  const [Title, setTitle] = useState("")  
  const [contents, setcontents] = useState("")    

  const imageHandler = () => {
    const input = document.createElement("input");
    const formData = new FormData();


    input.setAttribute("type", "file");
    input.setAttribute("accept", "image/*");
    input.click();

    input.onchange = async () => {
      const file : any = input.files;
      if (file !== null) {
        formData.append("image", file[0]);

        console.log(formData)
      }
    }
  }
  const titleHandler = (e : React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      setTitle(e.currentTarget.value)
  }


  return (
    <div className="post">
        <ReactQuill
        style = {{height : "650px"}}
          ref = {(element) => {
            if(element != null) {
              QuillRef.current = element
            }
          }}
          value = {contents || ""}
          onChange = {(content, delta, source, editor) => setcontents(editor.getHTML())}
          modules = {modules}
          formats = {formats}
          theme = "snow"
          placeholder = "내용을 입력해주세요"/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Post;
```

If you check FormData with Console.log, it comes out as an empty object.

Comment: What about input.files? is that also coming empty?

Comment: @SanishJoseph When I checked input.files, I saw that the value was coming in.

However, the picture is not displayed inside the Content.

Comment: Where and how are you passing the Formdata to the content? Share that part of the code .

Comment: @SanishJoseph

<ReactQuill 
onChange = {(content, delta, source, editor) => setcontents(editor.getHTML())}/>

this part??

Comment: What I meant Is, aren't you missing `handlers: {  
                    image: imageHandler  
                  }  ` . Your imageHandler is not used anywhere..

Comment: @SanishJoseph It has already been implemented as modules.

`const modules = useMemo(
    () => ({
      toolbar: {
        container: [
          ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "blockquote"],
          [{ size: ["small", false, "large", "huge"] }, { color: [] }],
          ["image", "video"],
        ],
        handlers: {
          image: imageHandler,
        },
      },
    }),
    []
  );`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236634/discussion-between-sunpl13-and-sanish-joseph).